# Cannot test deadLetterChannel in apache camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am trying to test the `deadLetterChanel` in apache camel,

here's the production code snippet (part of my RouterBuilder):

```
from(dateQueue())
        .routeId(ROUTE_DATE)
        .to(log(myConsumer))
        .transform().body(String.class, it -> myConsumer.consume(LocalDate.parse(it)))
        .split(body())
        .to(log(myConsumer))
        .marshal().json()
        .to(processorExchange());

errorHandler(deadLetterChannel(dlqDirect()));

// @formatter:off
from(dlqDirect())
        .to("log:dlq")
        .choice()
            .when(it -> ROUTE_DATE.equals(it.getFromRouteId())).to(dateDLExchange())
            // other when expressions here 
        .end();
// @formatter:on
```

And here's the test code:

```java
@Test
void testErrorCaseOfDateRoute_ShouldGoToDateDlExchange() throws Exception {
    // given:
    MockEndpoint dateDLExchangeMock = camelContext.getEndpoint("mock:test", MockEndpoint.class);
    AdviceWith.adviceWith(camelContext, ROUTE_DATE,
            in -> in.interceptSendToEndpoint(dateDLExchange()).to(dateDLExchangeMock)
    );
    dateDLExchangeMock.expectedMessageCount(1);
    dateDLExchangeMock.expectedBodiesReceived("invalid date");

    // when:
    producerTemplate.sendBody(dateExchange(), "invalid date");

    // then:
    dateDLExchangeMock.assertIsSatisfied();
}
```

The assertion fails!

However, if I changed the mock to intercept `dlqDirect()` (direct endpoint) instead of `dateDLExchange()` (`rabbitmq` endpoint), it works fine, but I want to include the `choice()` function in my tests as well.

I am doing mini-integration tests using RabbitMQ in TestContainer, so I really think to listen to the queue in `rabbitmq` instance and assert the message there instead of doing the test using Camel! (Can camel help here?)

> It worth noting that when I test this case manullay, I got my invalid message into the rabbitmq `date_dl_queue` which is bound to `date_dl_exchange`. ( I mean, it works)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using a route-scoped `errorHandler`, instead of using a generic error handler for all routes and then using when-expressions.

So, the code changed to look like this:

```java
from(dateQueue())
        .routeId(ROUTE_DATE)
        .errorHandler(buildErrorHandler(dateDLExchange()))          // <<< Notice this
        .to(log(myConsumer))
        .transform().body(String.class, it -> myConsumer.consume(LocalDate.parse(it)))
        .split(body())
        .to(log(myConsumer))
        .marshal().json()
        .to(processorExchange());


private DefaultErrorHandlerBuilder buildErrorHandler(String deadLetterUri) {
    return deadLetterChannel(deadLetterUri)
            .logExhausted(true)
            .logHandled(true)
            .....
            .;
}
```